# Send email automatically when a row in Column M is completed

Tags: google-sheets

I have a designed a form in sheets. When a row in Column M is edited, I want to automatically send an email to a specific email address - xxx@abc.co.uk.

The email layout looks like this:

To: xxx@abc.co.uk
cc: (Column Z Value)
Subject: (Column A Value) & " - " & " (Column C Value)

Hi (Column M Value)

Please look at this.

"TITLE - " & Column C

"DATE RECEIVED - " & Column D

"FROM - " & Column E

---

**Sample data snapshot**

---

**An example of a completed email**

---

**Code tried but only does half the job**

Comment: Welcome. This is not an uncommon question, and there are many answers on webapps and also StackOverflow. The solution requires a Apps Script and though you are new to all this, you will have to develop some apps scripts if only to implement an answer. This [Google guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) is a good place to start.

Comment: Sorry - also meant to mention that Google has some [Apps Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails) including one on "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send email when theres a change in a particular column on a particular sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119951/send-email-when-theres-a-change-in-a-particular-column-on-a-particular-sheet)

Comment: Oops - "develop some apps scripts"- meant to say "develop some apps skills". In any event, if you are really new to this, let me know and we will try and help you build an answer.

Comment: HiI have had an initial go, from what I can find on the web. Unfortunately, it only does half the job I want it to...

Comment: Great, we can solve this. But first, **YOU** need to add detail to the question so that it can be re-opened. Would you please make these edits to the question: 1) include a snapshot/image sample of a few rows of the form including headers and Column M!, 2) using some sample data, create an example of a successful email, and 3) add the code that you tried AND explain what you mean by _"it only does half the job"_. I've simplified some of your question and title, and created headings where you can insert the detailed things that I've described. Over to you.

Comment: Suggest you also look at [Email notification when any cell in specific column is changed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/149137/196152).